# Python convert unicode to ASCII

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I have a list of strings with various different characters that are similar to latin ones, I get these from a website that I download from using urllib2. The website is encoded in utf-8. However, after trying quite a few variations, I can't figure out how to convert this to simple ASCII equivalent. So for example, one of the strings I have is:

```
u'Atl\xc3\xa9tico Madrid'
```

In plain text it's "Atlético Madrid", what I want, is to change it to just "Atletico Madrid".
If I use simple unidecode on this, I get "AtlA(c)tico Madrid". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have UTF-8 bytes in a Unicode string. That's **not** a proper Unicode string, that's a [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake):

```
>>> print u'Atl\xc3\xa9tico Madrid'
AtlÃ©tico Madrid
```

Repair your string first:

```
>>> u'Atl\xc3\xa9tico Madrid'.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
u'Atl\xe9tico Madrid'
>>> print u'Atl\xc3\xa9tico Madrid'.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
Atlético Madrid
```

and Unidecode will give you what you expected:

```
>>> import unidecode
>>> unidecode.unidecode(u'Atl\xc3\xa9tico Madrid')
'AtlA(c)tico Madrid'
>>> unidecode.unidecode(u'Atl\xc3\xa9tico Madrid'.encode('latin1').decode('utf8'))
'Atletico Madrid'
```

Better still would be to read your data correctly in the first place; you appear to have decoded the data as Latin-1 (or perhaps the Windows CP-1252 codepage) rather than as UTF-8.

Comment: Your solution obviously worked, but after reading the last part, I realized that I could just add .decode("utf-8") right after the urllib2 request read(), so now I can simply run unidecode() without any other encode/decodes. Thanks!